# Can a spamhouse listing affect your IP long term?

Tags: email, spam, blacklist

Lately I am getting a lot of mail delivery fails like 20% of the time.

It used to be less, then some domain on our shared hosting was blacklisted in spamhouse and all emails couldn't be delivered.

The problem was sorted and our IP isn't blacklisted any more, but the delivery rate is strangely low lately.

So I am asking if your IP is delisted from *spamhouse* can you still be affected by the previous listing?

Also what can be learned from a mail delivery fail?

This is the error I'm getting:

```
A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:
```

Comment: Quite frequently more than single black listing is triggered by "disputable email sending". Are you **sure** your IP is not blacklisted elsewhere?

Comment: Not that im aware of. Where can I check?

Comment: Also what is disputable email sending? Like someone using the IP for spamming? The original listing was because of a hacked site on this IP.

Comment: 1) DNSBL listing check: Choose one of a few services listed at the first page of https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=dnsbl+check ; Some listings are not worth any serious consideration (e.g. APEWS) 2) "hacked (web?) site on this IP" most likely get not only spamhause attention.

Comment: I checked but its not listed there. The hacked site was removed, and the spamhouse listing disappeared. strange. Maybe its the recepients servers? Although that would be strange.

Comment: Your error message was cut off. The important part is immediately after the part you posted.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here would appear as though the IP for your shared server has been blacklisted by a range of other blacklist companies, and/or the receiving mail servers still have the Spamhaus blacklist in their cache.

Many companies with email servers, in order to speed up email handling times, and decrease overhead, cache the blacklist records from Spamhaus for a pre-defined period of time, especially the DNS based blacklists which may very well be routed through a caching DNS server before being sent to Spamhaus. How long this will last for depends on the receiving companies.

The other thing that it could be as stated above is that the IP has been blacklisted by another blacklist provider. There are well in excess of 100+ major blacklist providers out there, and short of contacting each and every one to find out if the IP has been blacklisted there is a tool that will let you check 95+ of the major blacklist providers, the tool is located at http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx and can be used to check all of those blacklist providers. The way it works is to type `blacklist: {your ip here}` into the search field and click on the search button and that will run your IP through all the different blacklist providers.